# Google+ not signing in in Clash of Clans

Tags: google

I have tried to install the last update of Clash of Clans, it always failed, so I uninstalled it and installed it again. Succeeded.

Now I have to login to my village, I used Google+ before, so after I started the game it loaded then there's little G+ Sign in button, I tapped it, it loaded and then there was a blue button to sign in, I tapped it and it loaded for a while and then restarted the game

Now whenever I click sign in it shows that loading icon and then nothing happens, the game continues to show the tutorial

I have tried to clear Google Services Framework/Play Services/Play all with no luck

I have also tried to clear Clash of clans data without luck too

I have tried to continue the tutorial and creating new village and then signing in but meh

I am now very frustrated I want to restore my kingdom in Clash of Clans

Pleaee help.

Comment: I think you'd be best asking the developer of the app or on their [forums](http://forum.supercell.net/forumdisplay.php/4-Clash-of-Clans) as it sounds like it is an issue with the app rather than a general Android issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was a bit weird

Actually the problem was that there was a newer version of the game, they difference was in the minor release number

Neither Google Play or the game itself prompted me for the update, I downloaded the APK fro. third-party websites and sideloaded it and now it works pretty good

Also if you're are in the one of the blocked countries by Google, try some VPN app